# Testing multiple versions of Android app for an API change

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

In my app, I have an Android module which depends on an external configuration file (similar to an API). Each time I make changes to config file/API, I have to validate the new file/API against all older versions of my app - which involves uninstalling and reinstalling the app. I want to have one test app which can load the config file and test the APK version I can point at runtime (through a dropdown).

Can Gradle help here? If I could install different versions of my app at the same time, I can invoke the right version from the test app via a deeplink. I have already been through the Android docs for [building multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-apk-splits) but can't find anything useful for my scenario.

I can't add the code of all older versions in the app, because there would be a class name conflict. As a last resort, I am planning to copy the code for older versions and rename package to avoid conflicts - I will have to continue doing this for each release.

Comment: Have you considered building a test script for this?  The script would install app one via adb.  Run test.  Record result.  Uninstall app one.  Install app two.  Repeat.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any instrumented tests for my app. I guess this approach is also viable if nothing else works. Thanks!